# Memory error with large data sets for pandas.concat and numpy.append

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I am facing a problem where I have to generate large DataFrames in a loop (50 iterations computing every time two 2000 x 800 pandas DataFrames). I would like to keep the results in memory in a bigger DataFrame, or in a dictionary like structure.
When using pandas.concat, I get a memory error at some point in the loop. The same happens when using numpy.append to store the results in a dictionary of numpy arrays rather than in a DataFrame. In both cases, I still have a lot of available memory (several GB). Is this too much data for pandas or numpy to process? Are there more memory-efficient ways to store my data without saving it on disk?

As an example, the following script fails as soon as `nbIds` is greater than 376:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nbIds = 376
dataids = range(nbIds)
dataCollection1 = []
dataCollection2 = []
for bs in range(50):
    newData1 = pd.DataFrame( np.reshape(np.random.uniform(size = 
                                                          2000 * len(dataids)), 
                                        (2000,len(dataids ))))
    dataCollection1.append( newData1 )
    newData2 = pd.DataFrame( np.reshape(np.random.uniform(size = 
                                                          2000 * len(dataids)), 
                                        (2000,len(dataids ))))
    dataCollection2.append( newData2 )
dataCollection1 = pd.concat(dataCollection1).reset_index(drop = True)
dataCollection2 = pd.concat(dataCollection2).reset_index(drop = True)
```

The code below fails when `nbIds` is 665 or higher

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nbIds = 665
dataids = range(nbIds)
dataCollection1 = dict( (i , np.array([])) for i in dataids )
dataCollection2 = dict( (i , np.array([])) for i in dataids )
for bs in range(50):
    newData1 = np.reshape(np.random.uniform(size = 2000 * len(dataids)), 
                         (2000,len(dataids )))
    newData1 = pd.DataFrame(newData1)
    newData2 = np.reshape(np.random.uniform(size = 2000 * len(dataids)), 
                         (2000,len(dataids)))
    newData2 = pd.DataFrame(newData2)
    for i in dataids :
        dataCollection1[i] = np.append(dataCollection1[i] , 
                                       np.array(newData1[i]))
        dataCollection2[i] = np.append(dataCollection2[i] , 
                                       np.array(newData2[i]))
```

I do need to compute both DataFrames everytime, and for each element `i` of `dataids` I need to obtain a pandas Series or a numpy array containing the 50 * 2000 numbers generated for `i`. Ideally, I need to be able to run this with `nbIds` equal to 800 or more.
Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

I am using a 32-bit Python with  Python 2.7.5, pandas 0.12.0 and numpy 1.7.1.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you say exactly how much ram it uses when it fails? Maybe it is due to 32bit version?

Comment: With the first method (using `pandas.concat`) the process uses 638 MB when it fails. With the second method (storing the data in dictionary of numpy arrays) the process reaches a memory usage of 1.113 GB before failing.

Comment: If your environment allows it, use pandas on a 64bit Python

Comment: The above code indeed seems to work fine on Python 64bit. However I need to make it work for Python 32 as I need it to be portable to 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by usethedeathstar, Boud and Jeff in the comments, switching to a 64-bit python does the trick.
If losing precision is not an issue, using float32 data type as suggested by Jeff also increases the amount of data that can be processed in a 32-bit environment.

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially what you are doing. Note that it doesn't make much difference from a memory perspective if you do conversition to DataFrames before or after.

But you can specify dtype='float32' to effectively 1/2 your memory.

```
In [45]: np.concatenate([ np.random.uniform(size=2000 * 1000).astype('float32').reshape(2000,1000) for i in xrange(50) ]).nbytes
Out[45]: 400000000

In [46]: np.concatenate([ np.random.uniform(size=2000 * 1000).reshape(2000,1000) for i in xrange(50) ]).nbytes
Out[46]: 800000000

In [47]: DataFrame(np.concatenate([ np.random.uniform(size=2000 * 1000).reshape(2000,1000) for i in xrange(50) ]))
Out[47]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Columns: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
dtypes: float64(1000)
```

Comment: The line `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([ np.random.uniform(size=2000 * 1000).reshape(2000,1000) for i in xrange(50) ]))` triggers a memory error on my system. The line `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([ np.random.uniform(size=2000 * 1000).astype('float32').reshape(2000,1000) for i in xrange(50) ]))` works but triggers a memory error after the third call, and with the actual DataFrames in my code, using float32 allows me to create the first but not the second DataFrame before a memory error occurs.

Comment: as a commenter above suggest, you are hitting a problem with 32-bit allocation. it needs to find contiguous blocks in order to work. The way you are creating things by definition will fragment memory, so it may or may not work. best bet is really to install 64-bit python (addtl memory wont' help with 32-bit). All of the concatentation routines copy. You can also do a small size.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward (but using the hard drive) way would be to simply use shelve (a hard drive dict): http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

Comment: As mentioned, I would like to avoid saving data on disk if possible.

Comment: Why the downvote ? this answer is useful to one of the questions.

Comment: Would you mind commenting on how exactly this helps with what was asked? Because according to their own description, Shelve is just persistent storage. Meaning, you'd have to first load the DataFrame to memory, and then use Shelve to store it, you can't use Shelve _instead_ of using memory from what I can tell.